# Can a 50 Hz, 220 VAC transformer work on 40 Hz, 180VAC?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, ac-dc, synchronous, alternator

I am designing an AC to DC converter. My power source is a single phase synchronous alternator that has a voltage range of 170~260 VAC and a frequency of 40~60 Hz. Can i use a transformer designed on 50 Hz and 220 VAC to work on my alternator specs mentioned above?

Comment: Depending on where and when it was made, 220 VAC in Europe would require it to have at least 10 % margin on that rating before saturation. You are close though.

Comment: Why not use a SMPS, which has input voltage and frequency compensation pretty much built-in? You'll most likely need to get stabilization anyway - it's easier and more efficient to do it on the high side.

Comment: How sure you are, that SMPS will handle the range of voltage and frequency i proposed above?

Comment: But can it work on 40Hz 260VAC?

Comment: You asking me ??

Comment: 40 Hz and 260 Vac will most likley put the transformer into deep saturation and blow a fuse/destroy it. You need to keep you voltage*frequency product constant to 50*220 or less at all times.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Not product, ratio. Voltage/frequency ratio.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Can a 50 Hz, 220 VAC transformer work on 40 Hz, 180VAC?

Yes it probably can - the initial worry is saturation problems due to operating at the lower frequency but, with the voltage dropping to 180 V at 40 Hz, this produces virtually the same magnetization current as 220 V at 50 Hz.

Strictly speaking, if the transformer is nominally rated for 220 V at 50 Hz, you should run it at a nominal voltage of 176 V at 40 Hz.

Comment: Can i avoid the saturation by using thicker wire in designing the transformer ?
In fact, voltage and frequency both will decrease or increase, change in RPM of the alternator will affect them together. @Andyaka

Comment: Saturation current is due to the iron laminates in the core and not the wire thickness. If the volts:hertz ratio remains constant, then you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Be on the safe side by using a transformer designed for heavier load. So the iron loss due to lower frequency can occupy the margin originally designed for heavier load (copper+iron) loss.

Comment: Heavier load has nothing to do with it. Decreasing the frequency _WILL_ saturate the core unless the voltage is reduced. Load or no load.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the mentioned transformer, you will be running the risk that it will overheat when used at **260V, 40Hz**. This is because your design requirements are "broader" than the capabilities of the suggested transformer.

Comment: Overheating isn't an issue. Saturation is.

Comment: The transfomer i inted to use will never work on 260VAC and 40Hz. The power source is a synchronous alternator that its RPM fluctuate between 1300~1800, so it procuces voltage of 170~260 VAC and freq. of 40~60 Hz. Voltage and frequency will increace and decrease together.  At 170VAC freq will be 40Hz, and at 260VAC freq will be 60Hz.

Comment: @MahmoudT.Abuzayed That relationship is very important and should go in your original question. Please edit it. You will be close to saturation always but it should work.

Comment: I hope things will go on without big problems. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: With the additional information (that the voltage and frequency "track" each other), I agree with Mahmoud that although you are operating "close to saturation" it should work.